# How to find the most repeated value in arrays of MongoDB/Mongoose documents?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Let's say I have a collection with documents looking like this:

```
[
 {
    "username": "user123",
    "email": "user@123.com",
    "favourites": [
      {
        "location_name": "USA",
        "id": "10",
        "day": "19",
        "month": "7"
      },
      {
        "location_name": "England",
        "id": "12",
        "day": "19",
        "month": "6"
      }
    ]
  },
    
  {
    "username": "user2",
    "email": "user@53.com",
    "favourites": [
      {
        "location_name": "USA",
        "id": "10",
        "day": "19",
        "month": "7"
      },
      {
        "location_name": "Australia",
        "id": "8",
        "day": "8",
        "month": "10"
      },
      {
        "id": "5",
        "day": "4",
        "month": "1"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Basically I want to find the "favourite location of the month". The favourite location of the month is basically the location that was added to favourites in the current month, and that can be found the most inside "favourites" arrays of users

In the example above, after the query I should get an id of 10 and location_name of "USA". The reason: we are in month 7 (July) and location_name USA is found the most times amongst "favourites" arrays.
So how can I query this? If it can't be done directly with a Mongo query, I can manage with a JavaScript/Mongoose solution.

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should solve your problem. You must first do an `$unwind` to separate your array items into different documents, use `$match` to filter only the desired month, count the number of entries for each country and sort it using `$sortByCount`, and finally use `$limit`to bring only the one with more entries.

Just a note: Instead of using `$group` and `$sort`, you should use `$sortByCount`.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
    {"$unwind" : "$favourites"},
    {"$match" : {"favourites.month" : "7"}},
    {"$sortByCount" : "$favourites.location_name"},
    {"$limit" : 1}
]).pretty()
```

Comment: how can I do this with mongoose ? 
I am stuck with similar problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73800471/how-can-i-find-most-occuring-userid-which-lies-inside-using-mongoose-aggrega